# Flash drive with USB and bluetooth interface

Tags: usb, bluetooth, wireless

Does it exist a USB/bluetooth flash drive? I frequently need to copy data from a personal computer (I do not have bluetooth dongle) and a tablet. So I'm thinking about an hardware key acting as a flash drive but with both USB (for the PC) and bluetooth (for the tablet) interfaces.

Comment: Basically, you want to copy files from your tablet directly to your flash drive, correct? Is there something wrong with having two devices to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy files with the sequence: tablet -> flash drive -> PC (or vice-versa). What kind of devices are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to a regular flash drive and a separate Bluetooth dongle like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320166), both plugged into your laptop.

Comment: I understand now, but it works just in case tablet and PC are in a range, while I would like to copy data also in the case the tablet and the PC are in different locations.

Comment: I do not think that such devices exist. I know it isn't hardware, but what about a cloud service like Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc? This does require that both devices are connected to the internet however.

Comment: If your tablet support it, you just need a usb otg adapter. They are very cheap 1$-2$. I don't think that the bluetooth/usb exist!

Comment: Would a wifi flash drive also work?

Comment: @Cfinley: internet is not an option, I'm looking for an hw device.

Comment: @DeviLFisH: I know about USB OTG but is not always supported (expecially by iPADs) that's why I was thinking about Bluetooth, more supported

Comment: @badge-be: can you give an example of wifi flash drive?

Comment: [The sandisk connect](https://www.sandisk.com/connect)

Comment: What happened to my anwer?

Comment: I don't know for some reason it dissappeared. Maybe a moderator?

Comment: What about just a flash drive with two interfaces, one for your PC and one for your tablet (i.e, USB-C and USB-A?)